# Codename One - Using Material Design Icons font in TextField from external ttf file

Tags: java, material-design, codenameone, textfield, truetype

I am using Codename One for a project of mine.

I have to load the material design icons font.

I know it is included in Codename One fonts but I need to populate the text field writing the original names, like on the web.

I have to write, for example, "3d_rotation", instead of a unicode sequence.

```
//font file is in the src folder, it is recognized because a name different from "Material Icons" gives a sort of warning.

 Font materialFont =Font.createTrueTypeFont("Material Icons", "materialiconsregular.ttf").
        derive(40, Font.STYLE_PLAIN);

    textField.getUnselectedStyle().setFont(materialFont);
    textField.getSelectedStyle().setFont(materialFont);
    
String string="3d_rotation";

    textField.setText(string);
System.out.println(string); //OK it's "3d_rotation"
mainLayout.add(textField);
//results in a blank textField with hidden chars like a "3d_rotation" long string.
```

At runtime I see that the text field is populated with the string and not the glyph, and the string is blank, like white characters, I just can move through them with the cursor.

What's wrong?

Comment: The text field was designed for text. The material font doesn't include the alphabet and I doubt that would work.

Comment: @Shai Almog Will this work if I use a BrowserComponent and Javascript? var font = new FontFace('Material Icons', 'url(fonts/materialiconsregular.ttf)');

Comment: I doubt it. But haven't tried it. The problem is that once you go into browser component the "will this work" becomes a bit platform specific

Comment: @Shai Almog How do I have to write the path to access files like the ttf file that is in src foder? Is 'url(fonts/materialiconsregular.ttf)' a good parameter? Do you mean it is not univoque among platforms (but I just need iOS and the simulator for now)? However, I think I can pass the font as base64 data.

Comment: Fonts won't work as base64. E.g. iOS needs special install. You need to place the font in a directory that isn't src e.g. under the CSS hierarchy. It will be copied to the src root implicitly as part of the build.

Comment: @Shai Almog I do not need that the ttf file is officially in the src or css folder. I just need to put it in the suitable spot that javascript FontFace('Material Icons','url(path)'); recognizes it and loads. What is the right "path" value in that call?